# My Excel code using VBA and the QT function has worked for over one year but has now stopped working

Tags: excel, vba

Up to a few weeks ago the following code loaded the home page of the website into sheet "Data".  Now after execution "Data" is empty. Err.Number returns 0.

```
URL = "https://addressesandpostcodes.co.uk"

'Clear any previous data
Sheets("Data").Cells.ClearContents

Sheets("Data").Select

Set QT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

With QT
    .Name = PlaneID
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
   .WebDisableRedirections = False
'    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False      'Don't refresh here in order to handle errors
End With

On Error Resume Next
QT.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

If Err.Number = 0 Then
'No error occurred
    On Error GoTo 0
  Else
'An unexpected error occurred - tell the user
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print Now; QT.Name & " - Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    MsgBox "Web query name: " & QT.Name & vbNewLine & "Error number " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description, , "Web query error"
    AddHirer.AddressList.AddItem "No data"
    GoTo Finish
End If
```

I've tried changing the URL to other websites, e.g. URL = "https://www.findmyaddress.co.uk" or URL = "https://bbc.co.uk" and they all load the website into sheet "Data".

Any ideas of why this one website now refuses to load any data but works on every other website I've tried?

Comment: *why this one website now refuses to load any data but works on every other website*? Could it be because the source code of website changed